# How to urlencode on Shift_JIS on php?

Tags: php, character-encoding, encode, urlencode

Hello I have this URL (the website charset is Shift_JIS)

```
shop_search.php?pref=北海道**
```

but it should be converted to this before trying to access

```
shop_search/shop_search.php?pref=%96k%8AC%93%B9**
```

I have tryed this with no success:

- mb_convert_encoding($url, "UTF-8", "Shift_JIS") then urlencoding it
- using urlencoding encodes it to UTF-8 instead of Shift_JIS
- rawrlencode does the same as urlencode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to convert from SJIS to UTF-8, then url encode it, not from UTF-8 to SJIS, right?

As  you've said "the website charset is Shift_JIS".

```
<?php
$var = "北海道**";

$new = mb_convert_encoding($var, "SJIS", "UTF-8");

echo urlencode($new); // outputs %96k%8AC%93%B9%2A%2A
?>
```